# Webkit and jQuery draggable jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

As an experiment, I created a few div's and rotated them using CSS3.

```
    .items { 
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #FFC400;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #E39900;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E39900; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #E39900;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

I then randomly styled them and made them draggable via jQuery.

```
    $('.items').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: (80 * Math.random()) + '%',
            left: (80 * Math.random()) + '%',
            width: (100 + 200 * Math.random()) + 'px',
            height: (10 + 10 * Math.random()) + 'px',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + (180 * Math.random()) + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + (180 * Math.random()) + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (180 * Math.random()) + 'deg)',
        });
    });

    $('.items').draggable();
```

The dragging works, but I am noticing a sudden jump while dragging the div's only in webkit browsers, while everything is fine in Firefox.

If I remove the *position: absolute* style, the 'jumping' is even worse. I thought there was maybe a difference in the transform origin between webkit and gecko, but they are both at the centre of the element by default.

I have searched around already, but only came up with results about scrollbars or sortable lists.

Here is a working demo of my problem. Try to view it in both Safari/Chrome and Firefox. http://jsbin.com/ucehu/

Is this a bug within webkit or how the browsers render webkit?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing (and also in Opera). Did you ever find a solution/workaround ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a result of draggable's reliance on the jquery `offset()` function and `offset()`'s use of the native js function `getBoundingClientRect()`. Ultimately this is an issue with the jquery core not compensating for the inconsistencies associated with `getBoundingClientRect()`. Firefox's version of `getBoundingClientRect()` ignores the css3 transforms (rotation) whereas chrome/safari (webkit) don't.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/DAnGz/) is an illustration of the issue.

A hacky workaround:

replace following in [jquery.ui.draggable.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js)

```
//The element's absolute position on the page minus margins
this.offset = this.positionAbs = this.element.offset();
```

**with**

```
//The element's absolute position on the page minus margins
this.offset = this.positionAbs = { top: this.element[0].offsetTop, 
                                   left: this.element[0].offsetLeft };
```

and finally a monkeypatched version of your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucehu/34/edit).

Comment: and there's already an open issue for this as well: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8362

Comment: Didnt work for me (neither longer fix below). But the workaround is to rotate the inner object, and drag his parent wrapper. That way the position is totally unrelated to the rotation..

Answer (score 36):

I draw a image to indicate the offset after rotate on different browsers as @David Wick's answer.

[image: offset after rotate]

Here's the code to fix if you don't want patch or modify jquery.ui.draggable.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var recoupLeft, recoupTop;
    $('#box').draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var left = parseInt($(this).css('left'),10);
            left = isNaN(left) ? 0 : left;
            var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'),10);
            top = isNaN(top) ? 0 : top;
            recoupLeft = left - ui.position.left;
            recoupTop = top - ui.position.top;
        },
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.position.left += recoupLeft;
            ui.position.top += recoupTop;
        }
    });
});
```

or you can see the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ojoyuc/5)

Comment: It works like a charm. You're just missing one bracket after the drag : function. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, you solved one of my most irritating problem!

Comment: Perfect, the monkeypatch above this answer worked until a recent version of UI (v10) for me... this is a great solution, thanks!

Comment: Does the same monkeypatch work for resizable as well?

Comment: Awesome and +1 for not having to modify any jQuery code.

Comment: Still saving the day, some 6 years later!

Answer (score 21):

David Wick is right about the general direction above, but computing the right coordinates is way more involved than that. Here's a more accurate monkey patch, based on MIT licensed Firebug code, which should work in far more situations where you have a complex DOM:

Instead replace:

```
    //The element's absolute position on the page minus margins
    this.offset = this.positionAbs = this.element.offset();
```

with the less hacky (be sure to get the whole thing; you'll need to scroll):

```
    //The element's absolute position on the page minus margins
    this.offset = this.positionAbs = getViewOffset(this.element[0]);

    function getViewOffset(node) {
      var x = 0, y = 0, win = node.ownerDocument.defaultView || window;
      if (node) addOffset(node);
      return { left: x, top: y };

      function getStyle(node) {
        return node.currentStyle || // IE
               win.getComputedStyle(node, '');
      }

      function addOffset(node) {
        var p = node.offsetParent, style, X, Y;
        x += parseInt(node.offsetLeft, 10) || 0;
        y += parseInt(node.offsetTop, 10) || 0;

        if (p) {
          x -= parseInt(p.scrollLeft, 10) || 0;
          y -= parseInt(p.scrollTop, 10) || 0;

          if (p.nodeType == 1) {
            var parentStyle = getStyle(p)
              , localName   = p.localName
              , parent      = node.parentNode;
            if (parentStyle.position != 'static') {
              x += parseInt(parentStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
              y += parseInt(parentStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;

              if (localName == 'TABLE') {
                x += parseInt(parentStyle.paddingLeft, 10) || 0;
                y += parseInt(parentStyle.paddingTop, 10) || 0;
              }
              else if (localName == 'BODY') {
                style = getStyle(node);
                x += parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10) || 0;
                y += parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) || 0;
              }
            }
            else if (localName == 'BODY') {
              x += parseInt(parentStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
              y += parseInt(parentStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;
            }

            while (p != parent) {
              x -= parseInt(parent.scrollLeft, 10) || 0;
              y -= parseInt(parent.scrollTop, 10) || 0;
              parent = parent.parentNode;
            }
            addOffset(p);
          }
        }
        else {
          if (node.localName == 'BODY') {
            style = getStyle(node);
            x += parseInt(style.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
            y += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;

            var htmlStyle = getStyle(node.parentNode);
            x -= parseInt(htmlStyle.paddingLeft, 10) || 0;
            y -= parseInt(htmlStyle.paddingTop, 10) || 0;
          }

          if ((X = node.scrollLeft)) x += parseInt(X, 10) || 0;
          if ((Y = node.scrollTop))  y += parseInt(Y, 10) || 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

It's a shame the DOM doesn't expose these calculations natively.

Comment: I know it's an old question but I'm hoping for some help. I had a similar issue and I used both your code and the one David Wick has submitted. They work like a charm the first time when I drag the object, but then the jumping continues after I drop it and drag again. @ecmanaut do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

@ecmanaut: Great solution. Thanks for your efforts. To assist others I turned your solution into a monkey-patch. Copy below code to a file. Include the file after loading jquery-ui.js as follows:

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- the file containing the monkey-patch to draggable -->
<script src="javascripts/jquery/patch_draggable.js"></script>
```

Here's the code to copy/paste into patch_draggable.js:

```
function monkeyPatch_mouseStart() {
     // don't really need this, but in case I did, I could store it and chain
     var oldFn = $.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseStart ;
     $.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseStart = function(event) {

            var o = this.options;

           function getViewOffset(node) {
              var x = 0, y = 0, win = node.ownerDocument.defaultView || window;
              if (node) addOffset(node);
              return { left: x, top: y };

              function getStyle(node) {
                return node.currentStyle || // IE
                       win.getComputedStyle(node, '');
              }

              function addOffset(node) {
                var p = node.offsetParent, style, X, Y;
                x += parseInt(node.offsetLeft, 10) || 0;
                y += parseInt(node.offsetTop, 10) || 0;

                if (p) {
                  x -= parseInt(p.scrollLeft, 10) || 0;
                  y -= parseInt(p.scrollTop, 10) || 0;

                  if (p.nodeType == 1) {
                    var parentStyle = getStyle(p)
                      , localName   = p.localName
                      , parent      = node.parentNode;
                    if (parentStyle.position != 'static') {
                      x += parseInt(parentStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
                      y += parseInt(parentStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;

                      if (localName == 'TABLE') {
                        x += parseInt(parentStyle.paddingLeft, 10) || 0;
                        y += parseInt(parentStyle.paddingTop, 10) || 0;
                      }
                      else if (localName == 'BODY') {
                        style = getStyle(node);
                        x += parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10) || 0;
                        y += parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) || 0;
                      }
                    }
                    else if (localName == 'BODY') {
                      x += parseInt(parentStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
                      y += parseInt(parentStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;
                    }

                    while (p != parent) {
                      x -= parseInt(parent.scrollLeft, 10) || 0;
                      y -= parseInt(parent.scrollTop, 10) || 0;
                      parent = parent.parentNode;
                    }
                    addOffset(p);
                  }
                }
                else {
                  if (node.localName == 'BODY') {
                    style = getStyle(node);
                    x += parseInt(style.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
                    y += parseInt(style.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;

                    var htmlStyle = getStyle(node.parentNode);
                    x -= parseInt(htmlStyle.paddingLeft, 10) || 0;
                    y -= parseInt(htmlStyle.paddingTop, 10) || 0;
                  }

                  if ((X = node.scrollLeft)) x += parseInt(X, 10) || 0;
                  if ((Y = node.scrollTop))  y += parseInt(Y, 10) || 0;
                }
              }
            }


                //Create and append the visible helper
                this.helper = this._createHelper(event);

                //Cache the helper size
                this._cacheHelperProportions();

                //If ddmanager is used for droppables, set the global draggable
                if($.ui.ddmanager)
                    $.ui.ddmanager.current = this;

                /*
                 * - Position generation -
                 * This block generates everything position related - it's the core of draggables.
                 */

                //Cache the margins of the original element
                this._cacheMargins();

                //Store the helper's css position
                this.cssPosition = this.helper.css("position");
                this.scrollParent = this.helper.scrollParent();

                //The element's absolute position on the page minus margins
            this.offset = this.positionAbs = getViewOffset(this.element[0]);
                this.offset = {
                    top: this.offset.top - this.margins.top,
                    left: this.offset.left - this.margins.left
                };

                $.extend(this.offset, {
                    click: { //Where the click happened, relative to the element
                        left: event.pageX - this.offset.left,
                        top: event.pageY - this.offset.top
                    },
                    parent: this._getParentOffset(),
                    relative: this._getRelativeOffset() //This is a relative to absolute position minus the actual position calculation - only used for relative positioned helper
                });

                //Generate the original position
                this.originalPosition = this.position = this._generatePosition(event);
                this.originalPageX = event.pageX;
                this.originalPageY = event.pageY;

                //Adjust the mouse offset relative to the helper if 'cursorAt' is supplied
                (o.cursorAt && this._adjustOffsetFromHelper(o.cursorAt));

                //Set a containment if given in the options
                if(o.containment)
                    this._setContainment();

                //Trigger event + callbacks
                if(this._trigger("start", event) === false) {
                    this._clear();
                    return false;
                }

                //Recache the helper size
                this._cacheHelperProportions();

                //Prepare the droppable offsets
                if ($.ui.ddmanager && !o.dropBehaviour)
                    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(this, event);

                this.helper.addClass("ui-draggable-dragging");
                //JWL: Hier vindt de jump plaats
                this._mouseDrag(event, true); //Execute the drag once - this causes the helper not to be visible before getting its correct position

                //If the ddmanager is used for droppables, inform the manager that dragging has started (see #5003)
                if ( $.ui.ddmanager ) $.ui.ddmanager.dragStart(this, event);

                return true;

     };

 }
monkeyPatch_mouseStart();
```

Comment: I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined jquery-ui.js:1298

Comment: Same here - I wonder if anyone has come-up with an update of the above. :'-(

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this workaround as it preserves the original handler
It removes the transform then restores it

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // backup original handler
    var _mouseStart = $.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseStart;

    $.ui.draggable.prototype._mouseStart = function(event) {

        //remove the transform
        var transform = this.element.css('transform');
        this.element.css('transform', 'none');

        // call original handler
        var result = _mouseStart.call(this, event);

        //restore the transform
        this.element.css('transform', transform);

        return result;
    };
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/unloco/nqcedugp/2) (started from @Liao San-Kai jsbin)

Comment: this is great!  I was looking for this for years ;-)

Answer (score 5):

the answer of David Wick was very helpful... thanks...
here i coded the same workaround for the resizeable, because it has the same problem:

search for the following in [jquery.ui.resizable.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js)

```
var o = this.options, iniPos = this.element.position(), el = this.element;
```

and replace with:

```
var o = this.options, iniPos = {top:this.element[0].offsetTop,left:this.element[0].offsetLeft}, el = this.element;
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a lot of the solutions to get dragging working correctly. BUT, it still reacted wrong to a dropzone (like it wasn't rotated). The Solution really is to use a parent container that is positioned relative.

This saved me soooo much time.

```
<div id="drawarea">
    <div class="rect-container h">
        <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
</div> 



.rect-container {
    position:relative; 
}
```

Full Solution here (it's not from me):
http://jsfiddle.net/Sp6qa/2/

Also I researched a lot. And its just like this, jQuery doesn't have any plans to change that current behavior in the future. All submitted tickets about that topic were closed. So just start out with having parentcontainers that are positioned relative. It works like a charm and should be futureproof.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parent container of the draggable element to "position: relative".