# jQuery draggable with rotation - 'jerking' when dragging when rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webkit and jQuery draggable jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523747/webkit-and-jquery-draggable-jumping)

I have created a jsfiddle explaining the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/sCguA/15/

We have an image behind a template which we want the user to be able to drag to position it. They also need to be able to 'rotate' the image.

The code I've written in the fiddle above works perfectly for dragging the image, and rotating the image -- however, when the image is in a 'rotated' 90/270 deg. state, dragging causes it to 'jump'. I can't seem to figure out how to solve this!

Edit: dammit, this seems related: [Webkit and jQuery draggable jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523747/webkit-and-jquery-draggable-jumping) how did i miss this on my googling :(

Comment: If I understand you correct you want to be able to rotate the image and also to drag it, do I right ?

Comment: Yep - you're right, I want the image to be draggable at all times per the fiddle. @JohnKoerner -- yep, I realised that just after posting the question -- dammit! If this is appropriate (I'll be looking Tomorrow) i'll close my question.