# JQuery UI draggable move rotated element outside grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, jquery-ui-draggable, css-transforms

I use the jQuery UI draggable plugin to move some rotated (CSS3) elements. This doesn't work very well. One problem I could fix by changing a line in the library (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523747/webkit-and-jquery-draggable-jumping) but there is another problem. The draggable element moves one pixel up and left, out of the grid at each drag.

Is there a reason for this behavior? You can see the problem in die jsfiddle. You have to move the square. Best to the top left corner. After some drags you can see the the wrong top and left values.

In the fiddle the problem with jumping isn't fixed!
http://jsfiddle.net/jul35/vnQVh/1/